# Multiple spring data jpa modules(non spring boot) dependencies in a Spring boot app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-data-jpa

We are building independent reusable spring data jpa modules **without** spring boot. Let's call them db modules. These modules will be imported in another spring boot app. In the db modules, we are including

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

However, in the main spring boot have we have included

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

All spring dependencies in db module are of scope provided and expected to be present during runtime provided by main spring boot app. Is this the right way to do it?

Also, should each db modules have it's own properties file for db connection or should they reply the main spring boot app. All db modules connect to the same database. These modules represent different domains in the application.

Comment: provided scope is not transitive, that dependency won't be pulled in to projects depending on db modules. Is that what you want? You're expecting the starter to pull it in?

Comment: That's kind of what we want to achieve. All these db modules inherit from a parent pom which contains all these dependencies with provides scope. Wouldn't it be better for the consuming environment(spring boot app) to provide these dependencies to these db modules? Or should all these db modules bring their own dependencies along? This could result in problems since main spring boot app will also have spring core dependencies and could result in classpath pollution if they are on different version.

Comment: Short answer: All these db modules should bring their own dependencies along.

Comment: *"could result in classpath pollution if they are on different version"* That is up to the build script that packages the application for deployment to solve such discrepancies. Maven generally does that for you automatically. If you don't declare what other libraries you depend on, how would you even know if there was a conflict that needs to be solved. You wouldn't know until the code failed to run, and you might not detect that until already deployed for production, so you just crashed the production server, for something that should have been detected during the build.

Comment: @Andreas fair pont

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, using `<scope>provided</scope>` is not correct.

As the Maven [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#dependency-scope) says:

> **provided**
> This is much like `compile`, but indicates you expect the **JDK or a container to provide the dependency** at runtime. For example, when building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you would set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to scope `provided` because the web container provides those classes. A dependency with this scope is added to the classpath used for compilation and test, but not the runtime classpath. It is not transitive.

Said another way, it is "provided" by the runtime, outside of your deployment assembly.

If the dependency must be included when packaging your code for deployment, then you are certainly not expecting it to be `provided` for you.

Remember, your library need to tell the build system that depends on your library, what it needs to include other libraries as well as your library. That is the entire purpose of transitive dependencies, so by not making `spring-data-jpa` a transitive dependency, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: ok I understood the point about the provided scope. What about the datasource config. Should each module have it's own config or should it be provided by main app?

Comment: @bluelurker The module is re-usable. It doesn't know how to connect to the database. That is something decided by the application, not the module, right?

Comment: Yes the db modules are reusable. They will be used by other Spring boot apps in future. Yes, they can't exist as independent applications

Comment: I don't think this is right. `provided` can be used in more ways than are purely described here. I've used it for a similar, though not identical, situation to the OP. Lombok suggests you use provided scope, purely to avoid a transitive dependency, even though its used to *compile* your code. While a container might be the intention for this scope, I don't believe use-cases outside their intention is necessarily wrong.

Comment: @Michael If your module contains *optional* features that require extra dependencies, but they are considered optional because the use of the module may not need that particular feature, and hence doesn't need the extra dependencies, then yes, `provided` is a valid choice. --- That is not the case for your module, since the transitive dependencies you are suppressing by using `provided` are *mandatory*, so suppressing the dependencies is just plain wrong. Sure it work, because the application will include them too, but that doesn't make it right.